# How do I declare a function that returns a function pointer?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Imagine a function myFunctionA with the parameter double and int:

```
myFunctionA (double, int);
```

This function should return a function pointer:

```
char (*myPointer)();
```

How do I declare this function in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void (*fun(double, int))();
```

According to the [right-left-rule](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations), `fun` is a function of `double, int` returning a pointer to a function with uncertain parameters returning `void`.

EDIT: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/complex_declarations.aspx#right_left_rule) is another link to that rule.

EDIT 2: This version is only for the sake of compactness and for showing that it really can be done.

It is indeed useful to use a typedef here. But not to the pointer, but **to the function type itself**.

Why? Because it is possible to use it as a kind of prototype then and so ensure that the functions do really match. And because the identity as a pointer remains visible.

So a good solution would be

```
typedef char specialfunc();
specialfunc * myFunction( double, int );

specialfunc specfunc1; // this ensures that the next function remains untampered
char specfunc1() {
    return 'A';
}

specialfunc specfunc2; // this ensures that the next function remains untampered
// here I obediently changed char to int -> compiler throws error thanks to the line above.
int specfunc2() {
    return 'B';
}

specialfunc * myFunction( double value, int threshold)
{
    if (value > threshold) {
        return specfunc1;
    } else {
        return specfunc2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing it, but I already gave you accept and +1. That was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Thx. I just wanted to a) be clear and b) give hints for good practice.

Answer (score 12):

`typedef` is your friend:

```
typedef char (*func_ptr_type)();
func_ptr_type myFunction( double, int );
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a typedef:

```
typedef int (*intfunc)(void);

int hello(void)
{
    return 1;
}

intfunc hello_generator(void)
{
    return hello;
}

int main(void)
{
    intfunc h = hello_generator();
    return h();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char * func() { return 's'; }

typedef char(*myPointer)();
myPointer myFunctionA (double, int){ /*Implementation*/ return &func; }
```